# Do I need a separate provision profile for qlgenerator (Quick Look Plugin)?

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile, appstore-sandbox, quicklook

My app comes with a quick look plugin.
Currently I'm signing it with the same provision profile as the main app.

Do I need to have separate bundle id and provision profiles for my qlgenerator ?

Answer (score 0):

I've published my app on App Store with a separate provision profile and bundle id for the qlgenerator. It passed the review and seems to work just fine.
So I guess the correct answer is "Yes, you need to have a bundle id and prov.profile for the quick look plugin"